# Is there any way to determine text direction in a .NET Portable Library?

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library

I'd like to retrieve the text direction for a culture in a PCL project, but I couldn't find `CultureInfo.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft`.

For information, I target:

- .NET framework 4.5,
- ASP.NET Core 1.0,
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8.1
- Xamarin.Android
- Xamarin.iOS
- Xamarin.iOS (Classic)

This setup seems to be named *Profile111*. This is where my referenced assemblies are grabbed from by Visual Studio when I "go to definition". E.g.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile111\System.Globalization.dll`

Anyone knows if there is another way to retrieve it with my PCL configuration, or at least, what platform I should remove in order to gain access to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your concern is simultaneously supporting .NET, Windows 10 and Xamarin, you should consider switching the library to a .NET Standard profile.

.NET Standard 1.3 and higher all support `CultureInfo.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft`.

According to MSDN documentation, [`IsRightToLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.isrighttoleft.aspx) is only available on .NET and Universal Windows Platform (Windows 10), and there is no PCL profile that supports this particular platform sub-set. You are referred to .NET Standard profiles for this support.

Comment: Ok, this gives me matter to think about. Once I'll have dug à bit this .net standard 1.3 thing, I'll Côme back here. For now, +1 for thé pointer.